# React Redux success action does not trigger componentDidUpdate() to get latest state value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use React Redux to get the latest state values whenever it's updated but somehow the `componentDidUpdate()` only triggers on start action. Here's my code:

**Component**

```
import { fetchPaymentMethodsStart } from "@app/redux/actions/paymentMethods";
import { selectIsFetchingPaymentMethods, selectPaymentMethods } from "@app/redux/selectors/paymentMethods";
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

declare const _: any;

interface Props {
  paymentMethods: any,
  isFetchingPaymentMethods: any,
  fetchPaymentMethodsStart: Function
}

class PaymentMethodsTableComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.fetchPaymentMethodsStart();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props ) {
    console.log('DEBUG prevProps', prevProps);
    console.log('DEBUG currentProps', this.props);
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div id="payment-methods-table">
        <h1>Testing Table</h1>
        { this.props.paymentMethods }
        { this.props.isFetchingPaymentMethods }
      </div>
    )
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  paymentMethods: selectPaymentMethods(state),
  isFetchingPaymentMethods: selectIsFetchingPaymentMethods(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  fetchPaymentMethodsStart: (payload: any) => dispatch(fetchPaymentMethodsStart(payload)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PaymentMethodsTableComponent);
```

**Action**

```
import { PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES } from '../types';

export const fetchPaymentMethodsStart = (payload?: any) => ({
  type: PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_START,
  payload: payload
});

export const fetchPaymentMethodsSuccess = (payload: any) => ({
  type: PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_SUCCESS,
  payload: payload
})

export const fetchPaymentMethodsFailure = (error: any) => ({
  type: PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_FAILURE,
  payload: error
})
```

**Reducer**

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { ActionPayload } from '@models/index';
import { PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES } from '@redux/actions/types';

const initialState: any = {
  paymentMethods: [],
  isFetchingPaymentMethods: false,
}

export default (state: any = initialState, action: ActionPayload) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetchingPaymentMethods: true
      }
    case PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetchingPaymentMethods: false,
        paymentMethods: action.payload
      }
    case PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetchingPaymentMethods: false,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**SAGA**

```
import {
  fetchPaymentMethodsSuccess,
  fetchPaymentMethodsFailure,
} from '@actions/paymentMethods/index';
import { takeLatest , call, put, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES} from '@actions/types';
import { PaymentMethodsService } from '@services/paymentMethods/paymentMethodsService';
import * as  _ from 'lodash';


export function* fetchPaymentMethodsAsync() {
  try{
    const paymentMethods: any =  yield PaymentMethodsService.fetchPaymentMethods();
    yield put(fetchPaymentMethodsSuccess(paymentMethods));
  } catch(error) {
    yield put(fetchPaymentMethodsFailure(error));
  }
}

export function* fetchPaymentMethodsStart() {
  yield takeLatest(
    PAYMENT_METHODS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_START,
    fetchPaymentMethodsAsync
  )
}

export function* paymentMethodsSagas(){
  yield all([
    call(fetchPaymentMethodsStart)
  ]);
}
```

How could I get the updated state values after the success action is done? I can see on my Redux that it's getting updated, but somehow the `componentDidUpdate()` did not trigger.

I tried using setTimeOut() but it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In `mapDispatchToProps` you are declaring function with parameter  `fetchPaymentMethodsStart: (payload: any) => dispatch(fetchPaymentMethodsStart(payload))` but later on in `componentDidMount` you are calling the same function without one. Also you have it in your `Props` without parameter

Comment: On my action, it would allow an empty payload or even without passing a parameter using '?' `export const fetchPaymentMethodsStart = (payload?: any)`

Comment: Although with that said, the action is still dispatched. It still works, the componentDidUpdate() is also triggered after dispatching said action. 

But when success action was dispatched on saga the componentDidUpdate() was not triggered.